# Set OnclickListener For ListView Such that line selected in list is used as edit text in another class

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview

I have two classes for my translation app. One(Voice.java) in which we speak and RecognizerIntent gets our speech and displays it in form of a list. This is voice.java

```
package com.example.testing;

import java.util.ArrayList;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Voice extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    ListView lv;
    static final int check=1111;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.voice);
        lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvVoiceReturn);
        Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bVoice);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
        lv.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(arg0.getId()){
        case R.id.bVoice:
        Intent i=new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speak Up");
        startActivityForResult(i, check);
        break;




    }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(requestCode == check && resultCode==RESULT_OK){

            ArrayList<String> results=data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,results));
            }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


}
```

And another class TranslateActivity  which has one button and two edit text. Button works as translator of text from 1st edit text to translated text in second edit Text and speaks the translated text also . Code is as follows:

```
package com.example.testing;

    import java.util.Locale;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    import com.memetix.mst.language.Language;
    import com.memetix.mst.translate.Translate;

    public class TranslateActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
        EditText etInput

;
    EditText etOutput;
    TextToSpeech tts;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_translate);
        Translate.setClientId("d6159b31-37ba-4668-a31f-de0de6c47a38");
        Translate.setClientSecret("UMjSB3cHaSkLE+2xw4+a4dLIFahLdQQqh1YOhXdqfh4");
        Button Trans = (Button)findViewById(R.id.translate);
        etInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input);
        etOutput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.output);
        Trans.setOnClickListener(this);
        tts =new TextToSpeech(TranslateActivity.this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(status !=TextToSpeech.ERROR){
                    tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {   
        //get the text entered      
                String In =etInput.getText().toString();
                String s[]=In.split(" ");
                //String out[]=  new String[3];
                String str=new String();
                String outString=new String();
                //String Out;
                try {
                    for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++){
                         if(s[i].equals("who")){
                             str="whoa";
                            //etOutput.setText("whoa");
                            //str=etOutput.getText().toString();
                            //tts.speak(str,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);    
                        }else if(s[i].equals("are")){
                          //    etOutput.setText("arey");
                              str="arey";
                            //str=etOutput.getText().toString();
                            //tts.speak(str,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                        }else if(s[i].equals("you")){
                         str="ram";

                            //etOutput.setText("your");
                            //str=etOutput.getText().toString();
                            //tts.speak(str,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                        }   
                         outString+=str ;
                         outString+=" ";

                    }
                    tts.speak(outString,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                  //  String Out = Translate.execute(In, Language.AUTO_DETECT, Language.FRENCH);

               //   etInput.setText(Out);
        //        etOutput.setText(Out);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
}
}
```

Now I want an on click listener for list view such that whatever line  I click on list View, it gets used as edit Text of 2nd class(TranslateActivity.java) and gets translated without clicking the button on 2nd class. That is functionality of button in 2nd class is done by just clicking on list view in 1st class.Anyone who knows how to do this?

Comment: Whether u want the selected text in listview??

Comment: @Subburaj yes I want selected text in list view and that text to show up in edit text of other class

Comment: you can get the itemAtposition in listview setonitemclick listener and you can get in another class using intent..

Comment: @Subburaj Can u write the code for itemAtposition code....I am trying from yesterday but application crashes as I click on item in list view.......

Comment: Post ur code for and error stack..